# How do I properly scrape the Nextdoor website using cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I seem to be correctly following how to scrape a website, and what I have been doing has been working for almost every other website. However, when I try it with Nextdoor, it doesn't seem to output anything useful.

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const URL = 'https://nextdoor.com/topic/17821/';

request(URL, function(error, response, body) {
  if(error) { return  console.error('There was an error!'); }

  const $ = cheerio.load(body);

  $('a').each(function() {
    const text = $(this).text();
    const link = $(this).attr('href');

    console.log(link); 
  });
});
```

This is the output I get in my console when I run this code.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nextdoor/id640360962?ls=1&mt=8
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nextdoor
undefined
https://nextdoor.com/neighborhood_guidelines/#guidelines
/directory/leads
https://nextdoor.com/neighborhood_guidelines/#guidelines
https://help.nextdoor.com/s/article/1153496?language=en_US
https://help.nextdoor.com/s/article/how-to-mute-a-neighbor?language=en_US
https://help.nextdoor.com/s/article/hide-a-post?language=en_US
javascript:void(0)
javascript:void(0)
undefined
javascript:void(0)
undefined
```

Comment: it seems the site requires authentication

Comment: That output looks right to me...

Comment: What data were you expecting to see?